# Check car if available between 2 date laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-blade

App For Rental Car :
I need check car if available between 2 date and check quantity ("column name : qty"),
There is no need for a car more than the available number of cars (number cars booking < QTY car )
When change number 3 in the name of the column ('qty') does not work.
Query From Url : $PickupStartDate,$DropEndDate;

`Car::withCount('reservation')->having('reservation_count', '<', 3)->get();`

**Tables** :

**Cars**
ID | name | price | qty|

**Reservations**
ID | start_date | end_date | days | start_place | return_place | car_id |

check if car available for rental check we have a car between date

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = $PickupStartDate;
$end_date = $DropEndDate;

$cars = Car::with(['reservations' => function($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $end_date)
          ->where('end_date', '>=', $start_date);
}])->having(3, '<', 'reservations_count')->get();
```

Try this

Comment: i need check quantity not reservations_count > 3

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
    $start_date= $filters['StartDate'];
    $end_date= $filters['EndDate'];
    $query->withCount(['reservation' => function($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $query->where('start_date', '<=', $start_date)
        ->where('end_date', '>=', $end_date)
        ->orWhere('end_date', '>', $start_date);
    }])
```

in code Check
Car.qty< car.reservation_count